# Number of solutions in equation $x^2 \equiv a \mod(pq)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

How many solutions has equation $x^2 \equiv a　\mod(n)$, if $ n =pq$ and  $p, q$ - odd primes, $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. I know that it has something to do with $\gcd(a, n)$, but it doesn't really help. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you have the Legendre symbol at your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

The number of solutions is equal to the number of solutions mod $p$ times the number of solutions mod $q$, by Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Either of these last two congruences could have $0, 1,$ or $2$ solutions.  So possibilities for your answer are $0, 1, 2,$ or $4$.